# Putting two spans next to each other on same line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to display an icon, next to a description text on larger screens, but on small, just the icon.

I am trying this:

```
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <span class="glyphicon @line.ArrowType"> </span> <span class="visible-lg"><small>@line.EntityEventType</small></span>
        </div>
```

But it puts the text on a line under the icon. Without the span around the @line...., it works, but I need to conditionally show that text based on the screen size.

Is there a way to keep two spans on the same line next to each other?

Comment: span should be displayed in the same line. Is it a bootstrap issue? https://jsfiddle.net/q0vc6swm/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `.visible-*-inline` as `.visible-lg` is why you're having the issue. See [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> </span>  <span class="visible-lg-inline"><small>Yup</small></span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solved! Thanks! Never knew about that inline thing.

Comment: No problem and glad I could help.

Comment: Why .visible-lg doesn't behave like .visible-lg-inline. I don't see the sense here. Shouldn't not be "keep things in a line" the default?

Comment: @lilezek .visible-lg was deprecated as of 3.2.0 but is still included as it's equal to the class visible-lg-block (display:block). Check the CSS and the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
<div class="col-lg-1">
```

With some larger class:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
```

Being the maximum.

By default, span doesn't jump to next line:

https://jsfiddle.net/q0vc6swm/

## Edit

The problem seems to be visible-lg. Use a custom class instead, with media query:

```
.visible-custom {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .visible-custom { 
        display: initial;
    }    
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q0vc6swm/2/

Comment: Thanks. I updated your example with Bootstrap, and it does seem to work. Must be somthing else causing this on my CSS. https://jsfiddle.net/q0vc6swm/1/